# Asymptotic order of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, asymptotics

Let $a_2=1$. For $n=3,4,\dots$, let
$$
a_n=\min\left\{i=1,\dots,n:\frac{1}{i}\sum_{k=1}^{i}\frac{1}{k}\ge \frac{1}{n-1}+\sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{j(j-1)}\sum_{k=1}^{j}\frac{1}{k}\right\},
$$
where $\sum_{j=l}^{m}c_j:=0$ if $l>m$. Letting $f(n)=\frac{1}{n-1}+\sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{j(j-1)}\sum_{k=1}^{j}\frac{1}{k}$, it is not difficult to verify that $f(n)$ is strictly increasing in $n$, so $a_n$ is increasing in $n$.

I want to study the asymptotic order of $a_n$, and I tried to let $a_n/n\to a$ as $n\to\infty$. By the definition of $a_n$ and a Riemann approximation, we have
$$
\frac{1}{a}\int_{0}^{a}\frac{dx}{x}=1+\int_{a}^{1}\frac{1}{x^2}\int_{0}^{x}\frac{1}{y}dydx,
$$
which does not converge! I have no idea how to solve the equation for $a$. Please give me some hints. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please, don't deface your questions. Particularly after they have received an answer.

Answer (score 0):

$a_n=\min\left\{i=1,\dots,n:\frac{1}{i}\sum_{k=1}^{i}\frac{1}{k}\ge \frac{1}{n-1}+\sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{j(j-1)}\sum_{k=1}^{j}\frac{1}{k}\right\},
$

As a starter,
$\frac{1}{i}\sum_{k=1}^{i}\frac{1}{k}
\approx \dfrac{\ln(i)+\gamma}{i}
$,

$\begin{array}\\
s(i, n)
&=\sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{j(j-1)}\sum_{k=1}^{j}\frac{1}{k}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{j(j-1)}\frac{1}{k}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{j(j-1)}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1}(\frac1{j-1}-\frac1{j})\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k}(\frac1{i}-\frac1{n-1})\\
&\approx(\frac1{i}-\frac1{n-1})(\ln(n)+\gamma)\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Thanks. But I don't think the second equality is correct. When changing the ordering of a double sum, j will larger than k also.